# How to escape variables in bash?

Tags: bash, unix

I want to do something like this in bash:

```
echo "Installing WordPress Development..."
noroot wp core install --url=development.local.dev --quiet --title="Local WordPress Dev" --admin_name=admin --admin_email="admin@local.dev" --admin_password="password"
```

As far as I understand "local" in bash is a reserved word so this code should fail because of this, right? How to escape this local so that it would be interpreted as a string?

Comment: No, there shouldn't be a problem. `local` will be interpreted as a string in your example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to escape "local". This word has special meaning only when it occurs at the beginning of the line, like `local SOME_VAR='some value'`. Moreover, it can be used in a function only.

If you try to run the code in your question you will find out that it works and `--url=development.local.dev` is interpreted as a string without any special meaning.

Comment: +1. To be more explicit -- `local` is *not* a "reserved word" in Bash, but merely a built-in command. (And even the built-in command can be overridden by defining a shell function named `local`.) Bash doesn't really have any reserved words.